# Resampling, interpolating and merging several CSV files

Tags: python, csv, data-science

I'm working on a AI-driven project, and I'm stuck on a data formatting problem.

I collect phone sensors data for training my AI. The output of a single recording session looks like this:
[image]

My goal is to combine CSV files of inertial sensors (i.e. Accelerometer, Gravity, Gyroscope, Orientation etc) into one file. Most of the times such files have equal length and timestamps and work on a same frequency, but sometimes they happen to be slightly different. Example:

[image]

[image]

I suppose that this happens due to gaps in one of the files. As far as I know, it's possible to deal with this problem using such libraries as pandas, but I'm not sure how. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started in what you're trying to accomplish

Let's consider that all files contain a column called `timestamp` containing all timestamps

```py
import pandas as pd

df_accelerometer = pd.read_csv('Accelerometer.csv')
df_gyroscope = pd.read_csv('Gyroscope.csv')
df_magnetometer = pd.read_csv('Magnetometer.csv')

df_merged = pd.merge(df_accelerometer, df_gyroscope, on='timestamp', how="inner")
df_merged = pd.merge(df_merged, df_magnetometer, on='timestamp', how="inner")

# or as a one-liner

df_merged_v2 = df_accelerometer.merge(df_gyroscope, on='timestamp', how='inner').merge(df_magnetometer, on='timestamp', how='inner')
```

You'll probably have to clean a bit the merged dataset. Removing duplicated columns and or indexes if needed. But this should do what you asked